# Is there a way to modify connected walls, such as the walls in a house, using the Revit API?

Tags: revit-api

I am trying to modify a house, such as the length/height of a particular house using the Revit API. I have successfully modified an individual wall and also a selected wall among many other in the same project, by referencing the id of the wall. The same type of referencing that is by id of the wall, if done to walls in a house, does not cause any change in the dimensions. I am assuming it is due to the walls being connected.
Is there a different way of referencing connected walls? Nonetheless, how can I modify the walls in a house using the Revit API?

Below is the code for modifying walls using their ID, although it does not apply to connected walls.

```
if (wall.Id.IntegerValue.Equals(355391) || wall.Id.IntegerValue.Equals(355351)) 
    {
    wallLocation = wall.Location as LocationCurve;

    XYZ pt1 = wallLocation.Curve.GetEndPoint(0);
    XYZ pt2 = wallLocation.Curve.GetEndPoint(1);

    pt2 = pt2.Add(new XYZ(inputParameters.Width, 0, 0));

    Line newWallLine = Line.CreateBound(pt1, pt2);
    wallLocation.Curve = newWallLine;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, Tampering with walls specifically will lead to many problems like walls unjoin, misallocation, Annotations being deleted and of course, too many Revit Warnings that, for the most part, can't be handled.
My advice - or in this case it may be an answer - forget about modifying walls location using Revit API, Try creating walls from scratch if that will help.